# BlueSnap Marketplace - Vendor Information Tokenization

Tags: bluesnap

Where can I find the JS information for BlueSnap to tokenize sensitive vendor information such as ssn, passport/drivers license number before making the API call to create a vendor?  This would be the same step as creating an Account Token for Stripe https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-tokens.  The only other information I found was Client-side encryption http://developers.bluesnap.com/v8976-Basics/docs/client-side-encryption but seems to only cater to payment information.

Answer (score 0):

BlueSnap only tokenizes payment information (Credit Card number, expiration date and Security code) through the [hosted payment fields](https://developers.bluesnap.com/v8976-Tools/docs/hosted-payment-fields). They do not tokenize any other data.

I would email their support team to confirm the answer and express the demand for such a feature.

FYI The Client side encryption you linked to is an encryption, not a tokenization.

Comment: Ok I thought so. Maybe collecting vendor information for Bluesnap Marketplace onboarding such as their SSN, photo ID and other sensitive information is not in the scope of PCI compliance, in that case, I could use some encryption on my server then send that onboarding information to their API.  Thanks for info.